# PowerShell display duplicates in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv with headers like this

ID,Name,IP,Details

There are some value will be duplicated like this

```
1,John,192.168.1.1,Details1
2,Mary,192.168.1.2,Details2
3,John,192.168.1.3,Details3
4,Dick,192.168.1.1,Details4
5,Kent,192.168.1.4,Details5
```

Is there anyway I can select all lines with duplicated values?

Desired Output:

```
1,John,192.168.1.1,Details1
3,John,192.168.1.3,Details3
4,Dick,192.168.1.1,Details4
```

So far I have tried

```
Import-csv file | group | sort -des | select -f 10
```

but the result only group those with whole lines matching

I will be appreciate if anyone could lend a hand or show direction for me to solve this question. Thanks in advance for any reply

Comment: So it will return matches where any column has a match in another row in the same column?

Comment: Which are the duplicates and why? 1 and 3 because they are both "John", 1 and 4 because they are both "192.168.1.1", all of them because they are all "xxx" ?

Comment: @matt yes, but my code so far can only get whole line match...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler sorry for confusing example, I have edited original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood your problem up to 100%, but as far as I've understood you want something like this:

```js
# ID Name IP          Detail  
#-- ---- --          ------  
#1  John 192.168.1.1 Details1
#2  Mary 192.168.1.2 Details2
#3  John 192.168.1.3 Details3
#4  Dick 192.168.1.1 Details4
#5  Kent 192.168.1.4 Details5

$input = Import-csv .\input.csv 
$input

$uniqueNames = $input.Name | select -Unique
$duplicateNames = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $input.Name -DifferenceObject $uniqueNames | ? { $_.SideIndicator -like "<=" } | select -ExpandProperty InputObject


$uniqueIps = $input.IP | select -Unique
$duplicateIps = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $input.IP -DifferenceObject $uniqueIps | ? { $_.SideIndicator -like "<=" } | select -ExpandProperty InputObject

Write-Output ""
Write-Output "========================="

Write-Output "Duplicate Names: $duplicateNames"
Write-Output "Duplicate IPs: $duplicateIps"
```

Output:

```
ID Name IP          Detail  
-- ---- --          ------  
1  John 192.168.1.1 Details1
2  Mary 192.168.1.2 Details2
3  John 192.168.1.3 Details3
4  Dick 192.168.1.1 Details4
5  Kent 192.168.1.4 Details5

=========================
Duplicate Names: John
Duplicate Names: 192.168.1.1
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is so helpful!

Comment: @E.Chg: If it solves the problem, please mark it as correct on. Thx